# How to animate a diagonal line with TweenMax/EaselJS

Tags: html, canvas, easeljs, gsap

I have a constellation which i want to connect with lines. These lines need to be animated from a start point to an end point. I've provided an image to illustrate what i need as an end result:

[image]

All of these stars and lines are drawn with HTML5 canvas using easelJS. Provided bellow is my code so far, the "this.paths" variable contains x and y positions.

```
var graphics = this.shape.graphics;

graphics.beginStroke('#ffffff');
graphics.setStrokeStyle(1);

for(var i = 0; i < this.path.length; i++)
{
    var path = this.path[i];

    graphics.moveTo(path[0].x / 2, path[0].y / 2);
    graphics.lineTo(path[0].x / 2, path[0].y / 2);
    graphics.lineTo(path[1].x / 2, path[1].y / 2);
}

this.shape.alpha = 0.6;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all that you need is already in this demo
http://www.createjs.com/demos/tweenjs/tween_sparktable
you've got a set of coordinates like (x1,y1) and (x2,y2). Now you need to use the **Equation of a Straight Line** and draw the lines dot by dot for smooth animation, just play with delays for satisfactory results. Seriously, the demo covers all of this and more, you even can edit it right there! I've played with the code a bit and here is your diagonal line, just paste this code there and run
[image]

```js
var stage;
var prevPoint, dataProvider, rect = new createjs.Rectangle(20,20,700,360);
var bar, container, currentClip;
var selectedFunction, selectedItem, selectedIndex = 0;
var resetRuninng = false, startTimeout;
var clips = [];
var activeTween;

function init() {
    stage = new createjs.Stage("testCanvas");

    var Ease = createjs.Ease; // shortcut.
    dataProvider = [
        {type: "divider", label: "Ease Equations"},

    ];

    var eases = document.getElementById("eases");
    var cloneElement = document.createElement("a");
    cloneElement.href = "#";

    for (var i = 0, l = dataProvider.length; i < l; i++) {
        var item = dataProvider[i];

        if (item.type == "divider") {
            element = document.createElement("span");
            element.innerHTML = item.label;
            eases.appendChild(element);
            continue;
        }

        var element = cloneElement.cloneNode(true);
        element.id = i;
        element.onclick = selectItem;
        element.innerHTML = item.label;
        eases.appendChild(element);

        if (item.label == "linear") {
            selectedItem = element;
            element.className = "selected";
        }
    }

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);

    prevPoint = new createjs.Point(rect.x, rect.y);

    container = stage.addChild(new createjs.Container());
    bar = container.addChild(new createjs.Shape()
                                     .set({alpha:0.7, x:rect.x, y:rect.y}));
    bar.graphics.f("#000").setStrokeStyle(1)

    stage.update();

    startTimeout = setTimeout(run, 1000);
}

function stop() {
    Ticker.off("tick", tick);
}

function selectItem() {
    clearTimeout(startTimeout);
    if (clips.length > 0) { fade(); }

    if (selectedItem != null && selectedItem != this) {
        selectedItem.className = "";
    }

    selectedItem = this;
    selectedIndex = this.id;
    selectedItem.className = "selected";
    selectedFunction = dataProvider[selectedIndex].type;

    resetRuninng = true;
    //createjs.Tween.get(bar, {override: true}).to({x: rect.x}, 500).call(resetComplete);
    return false;
}

function run(easeType) {
    currentClip = stage.addChild(new createjs.Shape());
    clips.push(currentClip);
    prevPoint.setValues(rect.x, rect.y);
    activeTween = createjs.Tween.get(bar, {override: true}).to({x: rect.x+rect.width}, 1500, easeType);
}

function resetComplete() {
    bar.x = rect.x;
    resetRuninng = false;
    currentClip = null;
    prevPoint.setValues(rect.x, rect.y);

    run(selectedFunction);
}

function tick(event) {
    if (!resetRuninng && currentClip != null) {
        var hue = (selectedIndex / dataProvider.length) * 360;
        var g = currentClip.graphics
                .setStrokeStyle(1, "round", "round")
                .beginStroke(createjs.Graphics.getHSL(hue, 50, 50))
                .moveTo(prevPoint.x, prevPoint.y);

        prevPoint.x = bar.x;
        prevPoint.y = rect.x+ activeTween.position/1500 * rect.height;

        g.lineTo(prevPoint.x, prevPoint.y);

        stage.update(event);
    } else if (resetRuninng) {
        stage.update(event);
    }
}

function fade() {
    for (var i = 0; i < clips.length; i++) {
        var clip = clips[i];
        createjs.Tween.get(clip, {override: true})
                .to({alpha: clip.alpha - 0.4}, 1000)
                .call(fadeTweenComplete);
    }
}

function fadeTweenComplete(tween) {
    var clip = tween._target;
    if (clip.alpha <= 0) {
        stage.removeChild(clip);
        var index = clips.indexOf(clip);
        clips.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

**Update**:

here is another approach based on the simple tick method

http://jsfiddle.net/t21v9bo4/

Comment: did you run it on createjs site?
http://www.createjs.com/demos/tweenjs/tween_sparktable 
(click live edit)

Comment: is there any way you could make this simpler? I have cut out all of the fat and I can't figure this out? does the line depend on the rect? why? why can't i select the x and y for it to move from and to?

Comment: Got it.. I will update with some details eventually, so the tween animates a shape and the tick function looks at the shapes position and periodically draws lines between the steps to "animate" between the points. Clever.

Comment: yeah, the code is an example, provided by Createjs, it only gives a direction, an idea for further development. here is another approach http://jsfiddle.net/t21v9bo4/ you can take with the simple tick method.

Comment: You should add this to your answer I think the jsfiddle is more helpful than the original example you gave.